# add a primary key to new table created by query result

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to create a table using query result. But I want to also add a auto increment primary key field to it. Is it possible to achieve it using SQLite?

Example:
Select two fields from table_a. But I want the output schema as (id, field_a, field_b).

```
create table foo as
    select field_a, field_b
    from tablel_a
```

Currently using SQLite 3, but solutions using other database systems are also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with a single statement; `CREATE TABLE ... AS ...` does not create constraints.

You have to use two statements:

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [...] );
INSERT INTO foo (...) SELECT ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

by default sqlite adds  a **rowid** column in every table you create , so unless there's some specific need here, you can use this **rowid** column

check this out https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid